# Python request AERIUS calculation

Tags: python, python-requests, http-post

I'm relatively new to the python requests library.
I want to execute a calculation by sending a post request to AERIUS connect, but When I try to do so, I always obtain an error and never a valid response.
Here you can find the swagger API information:
https://connect.aerius.nl/api/
https://connect.aerius.nl/api/?urls.primaryName=WNB%20berekeningen

```
import requests
import base64

# Define the request payload
payload = {
    "options": {
        "name": "Optional calculation name",
        "calculationYear": 2023,
        "sendEmail": True,
        "outputType": "PDF",
        "calculationPointsType": "WNB_RECEPTORS",
        "appendices": ["EDGE_EFFECT_REPORT"]
    },
    "files": [
        {
            "fileName": "AERIUS_20230611122035_0_Scenario1.gml",
            "situation": "DEFINED_BY_FILE",
            "substance": "NH3",
            "calculationYear": 2023
        }
    ]
}

files = {
    'file': open(r"C:\Users\valen\OneDrive\Bureaublad\AERIUS_20230611122035_0_Scenario1.gml", 'rb')
}


url = "https://connect.aerius.nl/api/v7/wnb/calculate"

headers = {
    'accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
    "api-key": 'place your personal api-key here'
}

response = requests.post(url, json=payload, headers=headers, files=files)
print(response)
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an api-key?

```
headers = {
    'accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
    "apiKey": 'place your personal api-key here'
}
```

**"apiKey": 'place your personal api-key here'**